# What question has the highest view count with still a zero score?

Tags: discussion, voting

Purely out of curiosity, what question with zero score has the highest number of views? This question applies to the entire Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following [cross-database query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/397999) in SEDE if you can live with a dataset that is maximum a week old (refreshed in the weekend). I used the query from [Ben N](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269914/158100) as an inspiration for the query to run per database.

```sql
-- start create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      -- we have three sites that have borked DNS entries
      set @dbname = (case @dbname
      when 'StackExchange.Audio' then 'StackExchange.Avp'
      when 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta' then 'StackExchange.Avp.Meta'
      when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' then 'net.Mathoverflow.meta'
      else @dbname
      end)
      -- and one of those doesn't want to end with .com
      if @dbname <> 'net.Mathoverflow.meta' 
         set @dbname = 'com.' + @dbname
      exec #recursesiteurl @dbname,  @res OUTPUT
   end
GO
-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#recursesiteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #recursesiteurl;
GO
create procedure #recursesiteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)

      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #recursesiteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
GO

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_posts ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , id int
                            , title nvarchar(250)
                            , score int
                            , viewcount int
                            );

open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_posts 
               select top 1 @url
               , q.id
               , q.title
               , q.score
               , q.viewcount
               from posts q 
               where q.posttypeid = 1
               and score = 0 
               order by viewcount desc;'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select replace(
       replace(
       replace(site,
         '.StackExchange.com',''),
         '.com',''),
         '.net','') as [site]
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '/q/'
     + cast(id as nvarchar)
     + '|'
     + title as question
     --, score
     , viewcount
from #all_posts
order by viewcount desc

drop table #all_posts

drop procedure #recursesiteurl
drop procedure #siteurl)
```

Remarkable enough at the day of posting the highest view count of a zero scored question can be found on Apple.se: [How to open iPhone 5c locked with an iCloud account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116606/how-to-open-iphone-5c-locked-with-an-icloud-account) despite what some of us might predict/expect.

Other results are:

[image: zero scored descending viewcount network wide]

Comment: The world has gone insane. SO isn't the first in the list WTF

Answer (score 2):

Using this quick-and-dirty query on the Stack Overflow dataset:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Id FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1
AND Score = 0
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC
```

I discovered that the most-viewed zero-score* question is ["Get restaurants near my location"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964976/get-restaurants-near-my-location).

Copy-pasting the same query into the Data Explorer for other sites will get you their top such question. (I can't find a unified data set for the whole network.)

On Mathematics (the second-biggest SE site in terms of questions), the winner is ["Probability of getting exactly 2 heads in 3 coins tossed with order not important?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364986/probability-of-getting-exactly-2-heads-in-3-coins-tossed-with-order-not-importan)

On Super User, the kind-of winner is ["How to get rid of large gaps in text in MS Word"](https://superuser.com/q/103799/380318). It had a zero score at the last data dump, but since then it has received a single upvote.

* There doesn't seem to be a convenient way of checking for the number of up or down votes, so the best I could do is net score.